# Is there an `exists` where clause I can use with firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Use case: find conversations where I am a participant.

Given a collection of conversations is there a way to use a where `exists` clause on a nested object's properties?  I am using an object with an id as it's key hoping that it would be something I can run a where query against.  Should I have put the participants field in an array instead?

```
 db.collection('conversations')
            .where('participants.${userId}', 'exists', true)
            .get()
            .then(() => {
                // ...
            });
```

Sample conversation object

```
{ 
  id: 'foo'
  participants: { 
    userIdA: {
       username: 'bar'
    },
    userIdB: {
       username: 'joe'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I recall something about starting at the first value. So `.where('participants.${userId}', '>=', ' ')` (a space being the first printable ASCII character). A `.orderBy('participants.${userId}')` might also work.

Comment: so the orderBy worked but the >= '' didn't work.  The orderBy trick makes me a bit nervous in case the behavior of that changes.  Is that set in stone somewhere in documentation that records with null in the order by clause are not returned in the set?  Alternatively, is there a way I should tweak my data schema to make this query easier?  Perhaps pulling the participants out of the nested object and making them top-level properties.. in which case I would hardcode conversations to have to particpants set at properties `userA` and `userB`

Comment: The order is pretty well defined at this stage, although I'm surprised that the `>=` didn't work. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your sample conversation object is a complete example, all you would have to do is set each participating userId equal to `true`, and then have your query like this:

```
db.collection('conversations')
  .where(`participants.${userId}`, ==, true)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    // ...
  });
```

If you needed to know more about a specific user, such as their name, you could just look it up in a `users` collection, since you know what their ID is.

```
db.doc(`users/${userId}`)
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    // ...
  });
```